# Peculiar behaviour while erasing an element from from std::multimap

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, multimap

I was trying to remove an element from a std::multimap while I am looping over it in a thread that manipulates it . I used [erase function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/erase/) in the following ways

When I do this

```
//mItr is base iterator which loops over the multimap

std::multimap<std::string, std::string>::iterator tmpItr = ++mItr;
healthyQ.erase(mItr);
mItr = tmpItr;
```

so that I can have validated iterator after erasing the element from multimap, the program stalls in erase() call . So I used it in the following way to get the next valid iterator :

```
mItr = healthyQ.erase(mItr);
```

It worked. It consumed a lot of time and I am still not sure where the problem can be

Comment: How exactly are you getting a "validated iterator"? You have an iterator to the erased element.

Comment: @juanchopanza After execution, both first and second scenarios should make mItr as the iterator pointing to the next element.

Comment: You do not have a valid iterator after the erase function. Instead, you have an invalid iterator, to what was a valid position before calling erase. The second way (`mItr = healthyQ.erase(mItr);`) is the correct way to do the operation (the assignment replaces the ++ incrementation you would normally do).

Comment: Note that `tmpItr` is equal to `mItr` even before the assignment because of the pre-increment, i.e. `tmpItr` also refers to the element you just erased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second way is [exactly how it is supposed to work](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/erase/)

When you hold an iterator to a tree-based container and you erase it, it alters the pointers between the various nodes pointing to this node (and others). Even if you would know exactly what this node is (through the iterator), you are left with no indication what is the next node (and consequently, the next iterator). Because of this, the `erase` method *first* finds the next node, performs the erase, and then returns an iterator to this next node.

You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Removal) how removal works in a red-black tree.

Comment: At several places on sf, first solution is proposed to get the next validated iterator

Comment: you rightly mentioned that the second case is the best way to erase.

Comment: @cbinder: *"At several places on sf"* - what's sf?  Did you mean so (Stack Overflow)?  If so please show where - we can try to fix it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You invalidated the iterator by calling `erase()` function. So when you capture the iterator returns from `erase()` and reuse later  you are properly handling the iterator and avoiding iterator invalidation.